# using arg beyond ipcRenderer electron?

Tags: electron, ipc, ipcrenderer, ipcmain

So I have this code and the arg is getting sent through from Main.

```
    ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', 'async ping')

    ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', (event, arg) => {
      console.log(arg);
    });
```

I would like to be able to use the arg outside of the ipcRenderer function but I can't get it out.
Is this even possible and if so then how? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the value into an object property outside of the listener scope:

```js
const data = {
  arg: ''
}

ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', (event, arg) => {
  data.arg = arg
})

function someFunction (data) {
  if (data.arg === 'whatever') {
    ...
  }
}
```

When `data.arg` value changes, all the other functions it will get the updated value